# Mining pattern on PoA

Tags: mining, parity, proof-of-authority, poa

I've setup a small network with two nodes using authorityRound engine (parity). My question is about the mining. If I have two validators (A and B), who will mining the blocks? the node A or B?

I ask because in my block explorer I see always that the author is the same:

For example, I see something like this:

block | hash | author

## 1    | 0x.. | A

## 2    | 0x.. | A

## 3    | 0x.. | A

## 4    | 0x.. | A

## n    | 0x.. | A

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I'm using this settings:

- genesis chain

[image]

- The Smart contract for to manage the validators was copied from https://github.com/paritytech/contracts/issues/96

  contract AdminValidatorList {
          address public owner;

  ```
  address[] public validatorList = [<your first validator address>];
  address[] public pendingList = [<your first validator address>];

  mapping(address => bool) public isAdmin;

  modifier onlyAdmin() {
      require(isAdmin[msg.sender] == true);
      _;
  }

  event validatorAdded(address newvalidator);
  event validatorRemoved(address oldvalidator);
  event adminAdded(address newadmin);
  event adminRemoved(address oldadmin);
  event InitiateChange(bytes32 indexed _parent_hash, address[] _new_set);

  function AdminValidatorList() public {
      isAdmin[validatorList[0]] = true;       
  }

  // Called on every block to update node validator list.
  function getValidators() public constant returns (address[] _validators) {
      return validatorList;
  }

  function getPendingValidators() public constant returns (address[] _p) {
      return pendingList;
  }

  // Add a validator to the list.
  function addValidator(address validator) public onlyAdmin {
      for (uint i = 0; i < pendingList.length; i++) {
          require(pendingList[i] != validator);
      }

      pendingList.push(validator);
      validatorAdded(validator);
      InitiateChange(block.blockhash(block.number - 1),pendingList);
  }

  // Remove a validator from the list.
  function removeValidator(address validator) public onlyAdmin returns (bool success){

      uint i=0;
      uint count = pendingList.length;
      success = false;

      // you don't want to leave no validators - can't delete any until you have a minimum of 3. 
      // This is in case your 1 remaining node goes down. Leave a safety margin of 2
      if (count > 2) { 
          for (i=0; i<count;i++) {
              if (pendingList[i] == validator) {
                  if (i < pendingList.length-1) {
                      pendingList[i] = pendingList[pendingList.length-1];
                  }
                  pendingList.length--;
                  success = true;
                  validatorRemoved(validator);
                  InitiateChange(block.blockhash(block.number - 1),pendingList);
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
      return success;
  }

  // Add an admin.
  function addAdmin(address admin) public onlyAdmin {
      isAdmin[admin] = true;
      adminAdded(admin);
  }

  // Remove an admin.
  function removeAdmin(address admin) public onlyAdmin {
      isAdmin[admin] = false;
      adminRemoved(admin);
  }

  function finalizeChange() public {
      validatorList = pendingList;
  }
  ```

  }

I know both nodes connect properly because if I use static validators works fine.

Comment: It should be A - B - A - B ... Please share your configurations to dig into it.

Answer (score 0):

I think only one node mines blocks because you have defined in the contract the first node's address, instead defining a list :

```
address[] public validatorList = [<your first validator address>];
address[] public pendingList = [<your first validator address>];
```

you have to add the other one using `addValidator` function or initiate your `validatorlist` with both addresses.